# Bullet Gem for Ruby on Rails App not working

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, bullet

I have installed the Bullet gem for rails to try and clear out some of my N+1 queries, however I can't get the gem to work.

First I added the gem to the very end of my Gem file and ran bundle install

```
gem 'bullet', group: 'development'
```

Then I added the following code to config/environments/development.rb:

```
config.after_initialize do
  Bullet.enable = true
  Bullet.rails_logger = true
  Bullet.bullet_logger = true
  Bullet.console = true
end
```

I then ran the following in the terminal (as per Bullet's docs):

```
bundle exec rails g bullet:install
```

I want to see something like this in the terminal whenever I make a new request in the app:

> USE eager loading detected
> Book => [:author]
> Add to your finder: :includes => [:author]

> USE eager loading detected
> Book => [:genre]
> Add to your finder: :includes => [:genre]

However I get no output in the terminal apart from the list of calls to the database. I have dug into the docs but see no obvious answer as to why it is not working.

Can anyone please assist?

Comment: Same here, simply not working. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the gem inside a block like this in your `GEMFILE`:

```
group :development do
  gem "bullet"
end
```